# Переконвертировать List в объект, используя Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Имеется ArrayList c такими вот значениями:

```
{"*","12","24","52","*","35","3","*","3"}
```

Мне нужно переконвертировать этот лист, чтобы получился массив объектов такого вида ( разделитель *):

```
{{"12","24","52"},{"35","3"},{"3"}}
```

Написал эту реализацию не на стримах.

Подскажите, есть ли возможность сделать это на стримах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно реализовать примерно следующим способом в два этапа - сначала разобрать исходный поток по спискам (и если под *объектом* подразумевается список списков, то на этом и остановиться), а потом сконвертировать списки в массивы:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("*", "12", "24", "52", "*", "35", "3", "*", "3");

List<List<String>> lists = list.stream().collect(
    ArrayList::new,
    (l, s) -> {
        if (s.equals("*"))
            l.add(new ArrayList<>());
        else
            l.get(l.size() - 1).add(s);
    },
    ArrayList::addAll
);

String[][] strings = lists.stream()
    .map(l -> l.toArray(new String[l.size()]))
    .toArray(String[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(strings));

// out: [[12, 24, 52], [35, 3], [3]]
```

Только зачем?

Comment: Спасибо! А зачем что?

Comment: Зачем использовать для этого Stream API? В любом случае нужно будет последовательно обходить список, так что такая реализация в целом ничем не лучше (но и не хуже) реализации с циклом